# Partial unpacking of kwargs

Tags: python

Let's say I have a the following classes (consider that the classes have a couple more attributes, this is abbreviated for simplicity):

```
class City:
  def __init__(self, name=None, people=None, population=0):
    self.name: str = name
    self.people: Optional[List[Person]] = people
    self.population: int = population


class Person:
  def __init__(self, name='Anon'):
    self.name: str = name
```

I have a JSON file (the context of my issue is supporting i18ln, so the problem is similar but not exactly the same data):

```
{
  'London': {
    'citizens': [
      {'name': 'Bob'}, {'name': 'Alice'}
    ],
    'population': 2
  },
  'NY': {
    'citizens': [
      {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Dorothy'}
    ],
    'population': 2
  }
}
```

at some point in my code, I'm trying to initialise an object based on that JSON, something like:

```
london = City(
    name='London',
    population=data.get('London').get('population'),
    people=[Person(name=p.get('name')) for p in data.get('London').get('citizens')]
  )
```

if you notice, the names of the keyword arguments are the same, so using `kwargs` is a possibility, the problem is that I'm having to initialise the `Person` class as part of the unpacking. This actual class is a bit more generic so I can't really add extra behaviour to it, trying to be the least incisive possible.

I know about extended iterable unpacking but I was wondering if that would work for `kwargs` as well, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
def q(**kwargs):
    return kwargs

x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
q(a=5, **x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: q() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
```

(This code doesn't work) Ideally it would look something like:

```
london = City(name='London', people=[Person(**p) for person in data.get('London').get('citizens')], **data.get('London'))
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What error does your code give you? Which key is duplicated?

Comment: Like the example using the `q()` function, I haven't actually tried it on the code since it requires a couple more changes and it's more expensive. I'm just validating my idea with that small function beforehand.

Comment: Then how do you know your code doesn't work? I don't see any duplicated key.

Comment: @Unmitigated, the code does not work due to `an unexpected keyword argument 'citizens'`

Comment: It's not that, I'm trying to control how the values are assigned when I unpack the dictionary instead of simply unpacking it. This could be done manipulating the `__init__` of `City` but again, I can't really do that in my case since that class is more of a general interface.

Comment: @Onilol, so you're unable to change `City.__init__` signature?

Comment: yeah, can't change it. Not only the signature but the value attribution inside of it.

Comment: @Onilol, and why not using your initial approach with unpacking `**p` : `london = City(
    name='London',
    population=data.get('London').get('population'),
    people=[Person(**p) for p in data.get('London').get('citizens')]
  )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With class methods you can have more control over how the class is instantiated since the JSON keys don't fully match your parameter names and you need to transform the list of dicts to a list of Person.

Bellow are two options:

`from_data` which takes the city name and the whole data set to extract the values by the keys.

`from_kwargs` similar to the `__init__` expect the parameter names match your JSON keys to allow `**` unpacking and allows you to turn `citizens` into `people`

```py
class City:
    def __init__(self, name=None, people=None, population=0):
        self.name: str = name
        self.people: Optional[List[Person]] = people
        self.population: int = population

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, name, data):
        city_data = data[name]
        people = [Person(**p) for p in city_data.get('citizens', [])]
        return cls(name, people, city_data.get('population', 0))
    
    @classmethod
    def from_kwargs(cls, name=None, citizens=None, population=0):
        if citizens is None:
            citizens = []
        
        people = [Person(**p) for p in citizens]
        return cls(name, people, population)

london = City.from_data('London', data)
london = City.from_kwargs('London', **data['London'])
```

For your snippet trying to use ** to unpack data is failing because you end up providing too many parameters.

Not ideal but you can change the `__init__` signature to take `**kwargs` and then discard them

```py
def __init__(self, name=None, people=None, population=0, **kwargs):


london = City(
    name='London',
    people=[Person(**p) for p in data.get('London').get('citizens')],
    **data.get('London')
)
```

Another option is to transform the JSON data.

```py
transformed_data = {}
for city_name, d in data.items():
    city_dict = transformed_data[city_name] = { 'name': city_name }
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == 'citizens':
            k = 'people'
            v = [Person(**p) for p in v]
        
        city_dict[k] = v

london = City(**transformed_data['London'])
```

Or if you really want to use `**` then you'll have to prepare it first

```py
city_data = { 'name': 'London', **data['London'] }
city_data['people'] = [Person(**p) for p in city_data.pop('citizens')]
london = City(**city_data)
```

Comment: I would recommend `self.people: list[Person] = [] if people is None else people`, if there's no explicit use-case for distinguishing between "no people, ever" and "an empty list of people for now".

Comment: (In short, the attribute doesn't need to have the exact same type as the function parameter initializing it.)

Comment: I agree but I just left it as OP had

Comment: Went for data preparation as can't really add / edit base class

Comment: @Onilol I did suggest them as class methods but they can also be standalone functions `def create_city(name=None, citizens=None, population=0)` and be used in similar fashion